# My function returns None when the variable I'm returning has a string associated to it

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
database_id = []

def makeID(name, count=1):
    y = None
    x = str(name + str(count))
    if x in database_id:
        count = count + 1
        makeID(name, count)
    if x not in database_id:
        y = str(name + str(count))
        database_id.append(y)
    if y != None:
        count = 1
        return y
```

I am running this:
`print(makeID('Eric'))`

and I received None.
But when I print the database_id, it shows the list, ['Eric1'].

The variable y is also the string 'Eric1'.

---

I know it's not the most efficient but once it works fundamentally then I can make it more efficient.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do here, would you mind telling that please, so that I could be of help:)

Comment: When I test the code it returns "Eric1". And on inspecting the code, I don't see how it can return anything else if `databse_id` is empty.

Comment: If the first `if` is executed, then `y` remains `None` and your function will return `None`.  Also, learn to use `else`.  Repeating the condition (inverted) bloats, slows, and obscures your code.

Comment: You can easily solve this problem without using recursion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case it is returning None, because when you already have your name in your database_id, the first execution of your recursive method won't set the local y variable to your return value. Here's an example :

Let's say database_id already contains 'eric1'.

makeID('eric') -> x is contained in database -> makeID will be recursively called with (name, count=2) that will return y who is equal to to eric2 but it won't be catched by anything.

So in short, you should add a return at line 8.

And if you are interested here's a quick way to refactor your method to keep it recursive :

```
def makeID(name, count=1):
    unique_name = str(name + count)
    if unique_name not in database_id:
        database_id.append(unique_name)
        return unique_name
    else:
        return makeID(name, count+1)enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

In your condition `if x in database_id:` you never assign `y` meaning your condition `if y != None:` is False and does not execute (you have a return  statement in only that condition) essentially returning `None`. Furthermore you don't need to use recursion for such problems, you can easily solve it iteratively:

```
database_id = []

def makeID(name):
    count = 1
    while name + str(count) in database_id:
        count += 1
    user_id = name + str(count)
    database_id.append(user_id)
    return user_id
```